# Wordpress smtp.google.com issue on Windows azure

Tags: wordpress, azure, smtp, gmail

When sending gmail SMTP mail from Wordpress on a windows Azure website, something goes terribly wrong.

I managed to send once or twice a message, but mostly the authentication get's denied. And we get a lot of message of gmail, asking if we authenticated. Or if we are hacked.

Now the weird thing is that when i log in to the Gmail account on MY computer. Go to the following url and accept: https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha .
it suddenly works (for some time, and only form my pc).

As the worpress website is hosted on a Windows azure website, we can not log in on the server to navigate to this url:https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha from there.

Anyone got a solution for this issue? (As i don't have RDP on our azure Website, we can't access the machine to whitelist the ip).

Reference: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10336?hl=en

Comment: It seems that the range of IPAddress from Azure are being blocked on gmail. Try any other service to send emails. Example: send grid

Comment: @Thiago Custodio, thanks for mentioning to use another service. but i rather wait a bit more to see if anyone has a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to generate [an application-specific password](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1173270?hl=en) for your gmail SMTP if you enable 2-step verification.  That may help you to avoid manual CAPTCHA resolve.

I would still like to recommend **SendGrid** as you are using Azure. **SendGrid** is provided as an add-on in Azure. You can easily apply a SendGrid service and get 25,000 email per month for free.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the application-specific password saved the day! We are surely looking into SendGrid, but i was waiting for this solution. as i knew it was possible. Thanks a lot!